# Magento 2: Klarna payment is not visible on checkout page

Tags: payment-methods, payment, klarna, magento-checkout

I have installed Klarna Payments on Magento 2.4.5-p1
Installed Klarna module using the command: `composer require klarna/m2-klarna`
I have the correct testing credentials and enabled module from the Admin panel

But the payment method is not visible on the checkout page
I am below response:

```
klarna_kp:{client_token: null, message: "Klarna Payments ist nicht aktiviert.", success: 0, debug: true}
```

If anyone found the same issue, please add the answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check that your account is registered on Klarna Payment and you are using correct Production or Playground API credentials due to wrong credentials this error occurs.

So you need to check and update the credentials